# Rails apache mongrel mapping controller problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, mongrel

I am working with Rails for the first time and got the Apache-Mongrel integration working and have the index.html page showing up when I open localhost in the browser.
I created the controller (ruby script/generate controller Welcome index) and renamed the index.html file. 
 However, when I try to map to a controller in routes.rb (map.root :controller => "welcome") things break. I can start the ruby server (ruby  script/server) and browse to localhost:3000 works.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a reference to a controller named "Welcome". Renaming the Html file in the public folder is useless. You should create a controller called "Welcome " and then add a method, such as "index".

And then in the routes.rb file you should add: "map.root: controller => 'welcome',: action => 'index'"

Comment: I did create the controller, that is why running the ruby server works. there is something in the Mongrel/Apache integration that I am missing.

Comment: Did you try deleting that annoying html file ? Or otherwise you can try to access the controller by: "localhost:3000\welcome".

Answer (score 0):

Delete index.html file too, it will prevent your routes from working.

Comment: I did that. I rebooted the vm, restarted the servers and had it working. Then I changed the index.html.rb file and it stopped working again.